# Pandas separate a dataframe based on percentage of a column's sum

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe sorted from smallest to largest over ratio column, as below: (actual dataframe has thousands of rows)

```
identifier total ratio
1          15     0.21
2          500    0.21
3          70     0.56
4          200    0.75
5          540    0.99
```

and a cutoff value of:

```
cutoff = .3
```

and at the end I want two csv files, one with the 30% of the sum of total with the lowest ratio (type1.csv), and one with the remaining 70% (type2.csv)

So far I have tried just taking the first 30% of the rows, as well as trying to multiply the

```
total * ratio
```

and sorting on that new column, neither resulted in the correct lists at the end...

How to I assign weights for the total column's value, but then cut on the ratio column?

Comment: `s=(df.total*df.ratio).cumsum()` 
`s=s/s.iloc[-1]` then you just need slice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
cols = ['identifier', 'total', 'ratio']

data = [
[1          ,15    , 0.21],
[2          ,500    ,0.21],
[3          ,70     ,0.56],
[4          ,200    ,0.75],
[5          ,540    ,0.99]
]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

df['s']=(df.total*df.ratio).cumsum()
df['cutoff']=df.s/df.s.iloc[-1]

type1 = df[df['cutoff'] < 0.3]
type1[['identifier', 'total', 'ratio']].to_csv(index=False, path_or_buf='type1.csv')


type2 = df[df['cutoff'] >= 0.3]
type2[['identifier', 'total', 'ratio']].to_csv(index=False, path_or_buf='type2.csv')
```

Comment: could you explain what "df['cutoff']=df.s/df.s.iloc[-1]" does? My cutoff column is all 0s or NaNs and I it is not split where it is supposed to be.

Comment: I had infinities in my dataframe, fixed it.

Comment: df['cutoff']=df.s/df.s.iloc[-1] just sets an additional column so that you can see where you are going to cut of the dataset from one frame to another. You could compress the code to avoid this step, but thought it was good for illustration. 

df.s.iloc[-1] in this case is equiv of df.s.sum(), though the latter would be slightly less performant. So the output will be a ratio. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does! Thank you for explaining and for all your help!